# slidetoggle jquery won't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just wanted to ask why is it when im using jsfiddle to construct a ul li structured archives with slidetoggle, year>month>title it WORKS, but when I am to apply it to my archives section, only the year and month works, the titles won't display, do css have a problem with this?

```
   <?php 
include("connection/connect.php"); 

$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM posts ORDER BY YEAR(post_date) DESC");
                echo "<div id='nav'><ul>";

                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)){ 
                    foreach ($row2 as $year) {  
                    echo "<li class='current'><b>$year</b><ul>"; //year
                        $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) FROM posts WHERE YEAR(post_date)='$year' ORDER by MONTH(post_date) DESC");

                        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3)){ 
                            foreach ($row3 as $month) {  

                                echo "<li><a style='text-transform: none; color:#333; font-size: 14px;'>".date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 2000))."</a><ul>"; //month

                                $sql4 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE MONTH(post_date)='$month' AND YEAR(post_date)='$year' ORDER by post_date DESC");
                                while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql4)){ 
                                    $title2 = $row4['post_title']; 
                                    echo "<ul><li><a style='text-transform: none; color:#333; font-size: 12px;' href='pages.php?id={$row4['post_id']}'>".$title2."</a></li></ul>";//title
                                } 
                            }  
                            echo "</ul></li>"; //end month
                        } 
                    echo "</ul></li>"; //end year
                    }  
                } 
                echo "</ul></div>"; 

    }
    ?>
```

in jsfiddle this is how it looks like
**2014**
 January
 February
 March <<(clicked and the titles displayed)
  title 1
  title 2

in my archives section this is how it looks like
**2014**
 January
 February
 March <<(clicked yet the titles won't display)

by the way here is the code for the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav ul li:not(:has(li.current))").find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
    .click(function() {
        if (event.target==this) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I hope you could help me on this, thank you in advance.

You may kindly check my fiddle, [Jquery Slidetoggle](http://jsfiddle.net/gerald018/rx9mky6f/8/)

Comment: If you can add your HTML as the PHP generates it here, it would make it easier to determine the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rx9mky6f/6/

Comment: Could you please add a link where you have used this code? Seems like css is creating a problem

Comment: The issue is that event.target in your if statement is <b>2014</b> and this == 'li' element. That is why your click handler will never be executed. Actually I think that 'if' statement is redudant here. To solve this issue you need either remove <b> tag or better remove 'if' statement, you don`t need to check event target in this case.

Comment: i tried removing the <b> tag and the if statement, still it's not working. Im still wondering why is it that in fiddle the code works well while in my php it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last, I was able to get the answer.. I added an excess  tag near the title and that's the reason why it doesn't display, upon removing it, now my archives work very good.

```
<?php 
            include("connection/connect.php"); 

            $select_posts = "SELECT post_id,post_date,post_title, YEAR(post_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(post_date) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS postCount FROM posts";

            $run_posts = mysqli_query($con, $select_posts);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){

            $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM posts ORDER BY YEAR(post_date) DESC");
            echo "<div id='nav'><ul>";

            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)){ 
                foreach ($row2 as $year) {  
                echo "<li class='current'><b>$year</b><ul>"; //year
                    $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) FROM posts WHERE YEAR(post_date)='$year' ORDER by MONTH(post_date) DESC");

                    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3)){ 
                        foreach ($row3 as $month) {  

                            echo "<li><a style='text-transform: none; color:#333; font-size: 14px;'>".date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 2000))."</a><ul>"; //month

                            $sql4 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE MONTH(post_date)='$month' AND YEAR(post_date)='$year' ORDER by post_date DESC");
                            while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql4)){ 
                                $title2 = $row4['post_title']; 
                                echo "<li><a style='text-transform: none; color:#333; font-size: 12px;' href='pages.php?id={$row4['post_id']}'>".$title2."</a></li>";//title
                            } 
                        }  
                        echo "</ul></li>"; //end month
                    } 
                echo "</ul></li>"; //end year
                }  
            } 
            echo "</ul></div>"; 

}
?>
```

Anyway, thanks to those who tried to bear with my problem.